# Filter facebook events on date in FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm using a fairly simple FQL-query to query all the events by a page.

```
SELECT 
   eid, name, pic_big, start_time, end_time, location, description 
   , creator, host, venue
FROM 
   event
WHERE 
   eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = {$uid} ) 
ORDER BY start_time asc
```

In the time facebook stored it's `start_time` and `end_time` in timestamps it was simple to get only future events: `... AND end_time >= {$now} ...`

But facebook changed it's fields in timezone format. 
**Is there an easy way, preferably in fql, to only show the future events?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your problem, I just tried this out on the [Facebook Graph API & FQL Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and it appeared to work.

The only changes I made to your query was to replace `{$uid}`and `{$now}` with `me()` and `now()` respectively. The following query returned only future events for my account:

```
SELECT eid, name, pic_big, start_time, end_time, location, description, creator, host, venue
FROM event
WHERE eid
IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())
AND start_time >= now()
```

You can view this in action at: [Facebook Graph API Explorer Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20eid,%20name,%20pic_big,%20start_time,%20end_time,%20location,%20description,%20creator,%20host,%20venue%0AFROM%20event%0AWHERE%20eid%0AIN%20%28SELECT%20eid%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20uid%20=%20me%28%29%29%0AAND%20start_time%20%3E=%20now%28%29)
And of course be sure you provide the Explorer with a valid access token for your account.